# How to get full reference about csproj file PackageReference tag?

Tags: nuget, csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="$(Google_Protobuf_Version)"/>
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="$(Grpc_Net_Client_Version)"/>
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="$(Grpc_Tools_Version)">
```

I found this `.csproj` file, PackageReference didn't specify a version number, it was replaced by `$(Package_name_Version)`. What does it mean?

I check the Microsoft docs, but didn't find any information.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, `$(Package_name_Version)` is established in another file. This practice is commonly employed when a package of the same version is utilized across multiple projects. Updating the package version can then be accomplished by modifying the single designated location.

Example of this file, `CUSTOM_FILE.props`:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <some_nuget_reference>2.0.0</some_nuget_reference>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Usage of this file:

```
Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('CUSTOM_FILE.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />

<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="$(some_nuget_reference)"/>
```

It's important to note that the file must be created in the project's root directory.